# Get the featured image url of clicked post

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, twitter-bootstrap

How can I display the featured image of a post in a modal along with it's content.

With the help of a few online threads on similar issues, I tried this:

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail()) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
            the_post_thumbnail('my_feature_image', array( 'class' => "someName" ));
        echo '</a>';
    }
?>
```

Which unfortunately returns the same featured image for all posts.

On the same `header.php` where the modal is found, the following is there (above the modal divs):

```
$perma = false; 

if ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['phpost_slug'] ) ) #WHFIX 24/03/2015: 
    $perma = $wp_query->query_vars['phpost_slug'];

if( $perma ) {
    //we don't want to return a 404
    $wp_query->set( 'is_404', false );
    $phid = get_page_by_path( $perma, OBJECT, 'post' );
    $postvote = get_post_meta( $phid->ID, 'epicredvote', true );
    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $phid->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' );

    $pluginfeat = get_post_meta( $phid->ID, 'phog', true );
    $desc = get_post( $phid->ID )->post_content;
```

link to site: https://goo.gl/30a3QQ [Click on the post's row to open the modal.]

Comment: Can you post the context of this code i.e. your loop/template

Comment: Please post full code. Also if you are using this in loop then it must work fine.

Comment: The above when kept in the index.php works beautifully for the post thumbnails as you can see here: http://reignofmorons.com/

Comment: However, in header.php, I kept the above within a modal and it doesn't seem to work. Let me check what loop is used as I didn't initially made the page. Hold on.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Please check updated answer

Comment: @Roberthue Please check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using this outside the loop then use `get_the_post_thumbnail` to get the featured image for any post by supplying post id.

So your code will become this.

```
<?php
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" >';
            echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'my_feature_image', array( 'class' => "someName" ) );
        echo '</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tried your version just now and still the same thing unfortunately :(

Comment: Ok here's the weird part. I replaced this line: `echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" >';` with this `echo '<a href="#" >';` and it has now changed but to another post's featured image for all posts.